# Did Disarming Dumbledore save Draco Malfoy's life?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, severus-snape, wandlore

When Draco disarms Dumbledore in *The Half-Blood Prince*, we realize that

> the allegiance of the Elder Wand switched to Malfoy.

Later in *Deathly Hallows*, Voldemort

> kills Snape because he thinks Snape killing Dumbledore has made *Snape* the master of the Elder Wand.

We eventually find out later that

> Harry disarming Draco makes *him* the actual master of the Elder Wand and Voldemort was on the wrong trail to gaining actual power over the wand.

**The Question**
There's 3 questions really....

> 1. Did Disarming Dumbledore rather than killing him save Draco's life, as Voldemort thought that Snape killing Dumbledore made him the owner and was this part of Dumbledore's plan?? 
> 2. Does Draco realize how close he was to dying when Harry reveals the allegiance of the wand? 
> 3. Is it part of Snape's plan to protect Draco when he promises Narcissa he will do the deed if Draco doesn't?

I couldn't find anything on this, but if it's a duplicate, I'll gladly delete it.

Comment: Just as a reference, we don't typically *delete* duplicates. We mark them as dupes so the link to the other question, which makes it easier to find (in theory).

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Maybe. 3) No, it's about protecting Malfoys soul, and using Dumbledores death to further their plans by putting Snape above suspicion. Voldemort doesn't care about the wand until the start of book 7.

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand your last two questions. 2) When exactly do you mean? You mean when Harry and Voldemort are circling each other right before Voldemort dies? Does he reveal the allegiance any time before that? But Draco’s not in any real danger there..? 3) Surely, protecting Draco was the whole point of that Unbreakable Vow; or rather, Draco’s protection and safe-keeping was what made Narcissa ask Snape to make the Unbreakable Vow to begin with. She doesn’t really care that much whether Dumbledore lives or dies, but she cares a great deal whether her son is kept safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) "Did Disarming Dumbledore rather than killing him save Draco's life, as Voldemort thought that Snape killing Dumbledore made him the owner and was this part of Dumbledore's plan?"

I suspect you're right: In all likelihood, Voldemort probably didn't consider the fact that disarming would transfer a wand's power. Remember, one of the names of the Elder Wand was **"The Death Stick"**- as Ollivander said, the wand had left a **"bloody trail across history"**, and thus Voldemort would have expected a more violent transaction to secure the wand's passing.

It's also possible that the Death Eaters didn't mention that Draco disarmed Dumbledore, --but- given that Bellatrix makes a remark on this ("Dumbledore alone, Dumbledore *defenseless*"), I wouldn't bank on this.--
  edit: as pointed out by Janus Bahs Jacquet, no Death Eaters actually saw the disarming, so Voldemort bieng unaware of it taking place is a viable option.

> 2) "Does Draco realize how close he was to dying when Harry reveals the allegiance of the wand?"

In the film and the book, when Draco spots Harry on platform 9 and 3/4, he gives him **a nod of recognition***. Not the friendliest of gestures to someone who actively saved your life several times- remember the fact that Harry flew back to save him from the room of requirement- but still, nice enough considering it was a Malfoy.

> 3) Is it part of Snape's plan to protect Draco when he promises Narcissa he will do the deed if Draco doesn't?

It is in Snape's interests to protect Draco, certainly: first off, there's the fact that Snape had a history of favouring Draco in potions lessons etc., and Snape was head of his house. Secondly, there's the fact that Bellatrix was present for the formation of the *Unbreakable vow* between Narcissa and Snape- before which Bella had openly mistrusted and scorned Snape. We know that Snape was, ultimately, a proud man (shouting at Harry towards the end of book 6 "*DON'T* call me COWARD!"), therefore he would want to accept Bella's challenge to make the vow; not to mention the fact that, as a member of Voldemort's inner circle and influential amongst the other Death Eaters, Bellatrix could pose a huge threat to Snape, should he give her reason to question her identity.

In the unbreakable vow he promised both to aid Draco, but also to protect him- so yes, it was Snape's plan to protect Draco.

As David.S said, my first instict was that Snape and Dumbledore planned to protect Draco's soul, as the act of killing would tear it apart- when Snape asks "but what of my soul, Dumbledore?", it is made clear that the fact that Snape is aware Dumbledore is already dying (and possibly in pain), and the prior agreement they made before, means that he's doing him a service in ending his life.

Comment: Unless I’m severely misremembering, there were no Death Eaters present when Malfoy disarmed Dumbledore, so they don’t actually have any way of knowing (at least not for sure) that he did so, short of asking him directly. There are any number of ways Dumbledore might have ended up without his wand on him, after all.

Comment: As for question 1, isn't the answer "kind of"? What *really* saved Draco's life was Draco hesitating to finish the job, which allowed Snape to show up, quickly analyze the situation, and take Dumbledore out. Disarming Dumbledore first certainly allowed Draco more time, in theory. But it's not really clear what Dumbledore would have done if Draco had simply confronted him without disarming him since Dumbledore still planned on dying.

Comment: But Voldemort doesn't know that Dumbledore has the Elder Wand until he visits Grindlewald and interrogates Olivander.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet true, I shall edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @Ellesedil I don't tend to like answering "kind of", but I guess if that's valid then I'll edit. I suppose it's more the fact that Dumbledore knew that Draco wouldn't finish the job, seeings as he had a good measure of him.

Comment: @OrangeDog yes, but that doesn't make it invalid to mention in my answer, seeings as the question asked about the Elder Wand in the first place, so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @OrangeDog: I'm not sure what that has to do with anything. The Elder Wand is kind of immaterial to Voldemort's motivations at the time. Voldy was more interested in Dumbledore dying because he was a direct threat. Voldemort finding out about the Elder Wand and trying to take advantage of it was simply a nice, unintended benefit after the fact (which he still got wrong, but whatever).

Comment: As for the "kind of" comment on question 1, I'd probably rephrase it to "not really" instead and emphasize how the disarming of Dumbledore was simply part of his own hesitation. If Draco could have disarmed Dumbledore, he could have also simply killed him outright.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes.  If Voldie had known that it was Draco who did the disarming, he almost certainly would have gone after him when he realized the Wand hadn't accepted him.  Probably, he would have gone for a renunciation or disarming after Snape turned it over, then if that didn't fix the problem Snape's death, then Malfoy's (so, four potential transfers, instead of two).  It is possible the idea didn't cross his mind because he is so focused on death, or that he didn't know (if the DEs didn't know or didn't mention) but if it had been brought to his attention, he would have killed Malfoy as well just to be sure.
2. Maybe not.  The time between the revelations was pretty short, a single speech from "Malfoy was Master" to "Harry is Master", (to Voldie is Toast) and Malfoy might not have realized the danger before it was negated.  Also, I'm not sure how well known the details of Snape's death were - if it were known at that time that he was killed *for the wand*, perhaps Malfoy might have realized that the revelation of the disarming/mastery meant that he was next.  The danger was real enough, if something had interrupted the monologue before Harry was through, Malfoy was dead as soon as Voldie physically could to try to regain that advantage.  But I don't think the time or information was there for Malfoy to think about it.
3. Probably not.  I don't think it occurred to him as early as the Vow itself - it might have *after* his plot with Dumbles came into play, to assist in his suicide to break the ownership of the elder wand.  At the point he made the Vow it seems like the danger Narcissa was talking about was physical, from Malfoy's discovery or failure, while Dumbles was talking about spiritual (damage to the soul), and neither seemed to be *at that point* thinking about longer lasting repercussions like ownership of Dumbles' wand, or Voldie's paranoia about a follower who bested someone he couldn't.  Snape might have realized that his killing Dumbledore put his own life in the line of fire after the fact, but I don't think that was the original issue - and once he did, he would avoid pointing out the disarming since that would put Malfoy back into the line of fire.